# Asrock Firmware Update slowed down Ubuntu boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, 20.04, firmware

I updated my ASRock X570 Phantom Gaming4 Board to the latest Firmware as it is described on their homepage.
After that my Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS takes a lot more time to boot:

```
➜  ~ systemd-analyze time           
Startup finished in 19.721s (firmware) + 2.840s (loader) + 33.151s (kernel) + 5.894s (userspace) = 1min 1.608s 
graphical.target reached after 5.888s in userspace
```

I assume the additional time are the ~20 sec. from the firmware.

How can I analyze further to fix the problem?

Here are my full hardware specs:

```
AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6x 3.60GHz
ASRock X570 Phantom Gaming 4 AMD
32GB Corsair Vengeance LPX DDR4-3000 DIMM CL15
500GB Crucial MX500
PowerColor Radeon RX 5700 XT Red Devil
```

It's a Dual-Boot installation with Windows 10 - This operates normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After an `apt upgrade` the time is gone down to a normal level:

```
Startup finished in 19.737s (firmware) + 3.185s (loader) + 1.603s (kernel) + 18.304s (userspace) = 42.830s 
graphical.target reached after 18.288s in userspace
```